# Diferença entre task e shared_task no Celery?

Tags: python, django, assincronismo

Estou implementando um processo demorado em minha aplicação Django que precisar ser executado de modo assíncrono para evitar o timeout no navegador. Para isto, escolhi usar o [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) para executar a função demorada em segundo plano.

Li alguns artigos recomendando usar tanto o decorator `@task` quanto o decorator `@shared_task`, mas não entendi muito bem a diferença entre os dois. Tentei os dois e não vi nenhuma diferença em minha aplicação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O decorador `task`, por default compartilha as tarefas entres as apps:

```
app1 = Celery()
@app1.task
def test_task():
    pass

app2 = Celery()

print('test_task.name in app1.tasks.keys(): ' + str(test_task.name in app1.tasks.keys()),  
      'test_task.name in app2.tasks.keys(): ' + str(test_task.name in app2.tasks.keys()),  sep='\n')
```

**Saida:**

```
test_task.name in app1.tasks.keys(): True
test_task.name in app2.tasks.keys(): True
```

Mas note que o nome `test_task` sempre se referira à instancia vinculada ao "app1"

```
test_task.app is app1
Out[13]: True

test_task.app is app2
Out[14]: False
```

O decorator @shared_task retorna um proxy que sempre se conecta à instancia da app em uso:

```
app1 = Celery() 

@shared_task 
def test_task(): 
    pass 

print (test_task.app is app1)
```

**Saida:**

```
True
```

Agora façamos:

```
app2 = Celery() 
print('test_task.app is app1: '+str(test_task.app is app1), 
      'test_task.app is app2: '+str(test_task.app is app2), sep='\n' )
```

**Saida:**

```
test_task.app is app1: False
test_task.app is app2: True
```

Dessa forma o decorador @shared_task é mais util para bibliotecas e apps reutilizaveis.